# Picking a Random file from a folder in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I have a fodler on my local machine and I would like to pick a random file from it. I have tried using this :

```
    var files = fs.readdirSync(`/Users/...`)
    random_file = files[Math.floor(Math.random() * files.length)]
```

But sometimes I get this as random-file : **.DS_Store**

Could anyone help me fix this please

Answer (score 2):

Just run a filter and return filenames !== Ds Store

```
files=files.filter(fileName=>fileName!==".DS_Store")
random_file = files[Math.floor(Math.random() * files.length)]
```